# Google Chrome developer tools - Profiling results file format

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, profiling, google-chrome-devtools

I'm wondering is there any (un)official spec to .cpuprofile file format, which is generated when JavaScript profiling is used in Chromium-based browser's developer tools.

It is plain-text JSON so it is easy to get call tree data but I don't understand how to get timing information for each function.

Also I'm interested in hit count for every function.

Comment: Have a look at http://google-perftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/cpuprofile.html and http://google-perftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/cpuprofile-fileformat.html

Comment: Were you ever able to figure out how to get the timing information directly from the json file?

Comment: Updated link for @artm docs on github (via rawgit) https://cdn.rawgit.com/gperftools/gperftools/master/docs/cpuprofile.html and https://cdn.rawgit.com/gperftools/gperftools/master/docs/cpuprofile-fileformat.html however these links discuss a binary file format not the JSON one

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation provided by @artm](https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools/blob/master/docs/cpuprofile.html), the output can be analyzed with [kcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html).  What you need to do in order to load a Chrome .cpuprofile file into this is to convert it to callgrind format.

You don't mention your dev environment, so I can't say the best what the easiest way for you to go about this will be.

The documentation mentions [Google's perf tools](https://code.google.com/p/gperftools/) and kcachegrind for this.  These tools need to be built manually and I don't have a convenient environment for doing that.

Here is how I went about it on a Windows 8.1 machine with Node installed.

1. Install [chrome2calltree](https://github.com/jlfwong/chrome2calltree) for Node.  This command utility will convert your .cpuprofile to a callgrind format.
2. Install [QCacheGrind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qcachegrindwin/).  This is a Windows pre-built port of kcachegrind that will let you visualize your callgrind formatted file.
3. Convert your .cpuprofile:
   `chrome2calltree -i test.cpuprofile -o callgrind.profile`
4. Open your callgrind.profile with QCacheGrind.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a direct answer to your question , but [**this**](http://ejohn.org/blog/function-call-profiling/) is really awesome.

usage is very simple:

```
fireunit.profile(function(){
  document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
});
```

**You’ll get the following JavaScript object returned from fireunit.getProfile():**

```
{
  "time": 8.443,
  "calls": 611,
  "data":[
  {
    "name":"makeArray()",
    "calls":1,
    "percent":23.58,
    "ownTime":1.991,
    "time":1.991,
    "avgTime":1.991,
    "minTime":1.991,
    "maxTime":1.991,
    "fileName":"jquery.js (line 2059)"
  },
  // etc.
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is notable but the JSON format of cpuprofile probably has changed recently, so it may not be a stable format. In Chromium 44 for example (older version from their build archives) it looked like this

```
jq keys < chromium_44.cpuprofile
[
  "endTime",
  "head",
  "samples",
  "startTime",
  "timestamps"
]
```

In latest chrome 55 it is

```
jq keys < chrome_55.cpuprofile
[
  "endTime",
  "nodes",
  "samples",
  "startTime",
  "timeDeltas"
]
```

Just something to be wary of. I have not seen much if any documentation on the format though